# How to use HuggingFace nlp library's GLUE for CoLA

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, language-model, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers

I've been trying to use the HuggingFace nlp library's GLUE metric to check whether a given sentence is a grammatical English sentence. But I'm getting an error and is stuck without being able to proceed.

What I've tried so far;

reference and prediction are 2 text sentences

```
!pip install transformers
```

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-large-uncased')
```

```
reference="Security has been beefed across the country as a 2 day nation wide curfew came into effect."
prediction="Security has been tightened across the country as a 2-day nationwide curfew came into effect."
```

```
import nlp
glue_metric = nlp.load_metric('glue',name="cola")

#Using BertTokenizer
encoded_reference=tokenizer.encode(reference, add_special_tokens=False)
encoded_prediction=tokenizer.encode(prediction, add_special_tokens=False)

glue_score = glue_metric.compute(encoded_prediction, encoded_reference)
```

Error I'm getting;

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-4c3a3ce7b583> in <module>()
----> 1 glue_score = glue_metric.compute(encoded_prediction, encoded_reference)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nlp/metric.py in compute(self, predictions, references, timeout, **metrics_kwargs)
    198         predictions = self.data["predictions"]
    199         references = self.data["references"]
--> 200         output = self._compute(predictions=predictions, references=references, **metrics_kwargs)
    201         return output
    202 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nlp/metrics/glue/27b1bc63e520833054bd0d7a8d0bc7f6aab84cc9eed1b576e98c806f9466d302/glue.py in _compute(self, predictions, references)
    101             return pearson_and_spearman(predictions, references)
    102         elif self.config_name in ["mrpc", "qqp"]:
--> 103             return acc_and_f1(predictions, references)
    104         elif self.config_name in ["sst2", "mnli", "mnli_mismatched", "mnli_matched", "qnli", "rte", "wnli", "hans"]:
    105             return {"accuracy": simple_accuracy(predictions, references)}

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nlp/metrics/glue/27b1bc63e520833054bd0d7a8d0bc7f6aab84cc9eed1b576e98c806f9466d302/glue.py in acc_and_f1(preds, labels)
     60 def acc_and_f1(preds, labels):
     61     acc = simple_accuracy(preds, labels)
---> 62     f1 = f1_score(y_true=labels, y_pred=preds)
     63     return {
     64         "accuracy": acc,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in f1_score(y_true, y_pred, labels, pos_label, average, sample_weight, zero_division)
   1097                        pos_label=pos_label, average=average,
   1098                        sample_weight=sample_weight,
-> 1099                        zero_division=zero_division)
   1100 
   1101 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in fbeta_score(y_true, y_pred, beta, labels, pos_label, average, sample_weight, zero_division)
   1224                                                  warn_for=('f-score',),
   1225                                                  sample_weight=sample_weight,
-> 1226                                                  zero_division=zero_division)
   1227     return f
   1228 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred, beta, labels, pos_label, average, warn_for, sample_weight, zero_division)
   1482         raise ValueError("beta should be >=0 in the F-beta score")
   1483     labels = _check_set_wise_labels(y_true, y_pred, average, labels,
-> 1484                                     pos_label)
   1485 
   1486     # Calculate tp_sum, pred_sum, true_sum ###

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in _check_set_wise_labels(y_true, y_pred, average, labels, pos_label)
   1314             raise ValueError("Target is %s but average='binary'. Please "
   1315                              "choose another average setting, one of %r."
-> 1316                              % (y_type, average_options))
   1317     elif pos_label not in (None, 1):
   1318         warnings.warn("Note that pos_label (set to %r) is ignored when "

ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted'].
```

However, I'm able to get results (pearson and spearmanr) for 'stsb' with the same workaround as given above.
Some help and a workaround for(cola) this is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Can you please extend your code to give me a complete example which causes this issue?

Comment: @cronoik, sure. I'll add the code as an edit.

Comment: I get a different error message (reference is to long). When I remove a token from the reference it is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you are seeing this error with HuggingFace, you are trying to use the f-score as a metric on a text classification problem with more than 2 classes. Pick a different metric, like "accuracy".

For this specific question:

Despite what you entered, it is trying to compute the f-score. From [the example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/examples/text_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=Bliy8zgjIrJY), you should set the metric name as:

```
metric_name = "pearson" if task == "stsb" else "matthews_correlation" if task == "cola" else "accuracy"
```